# Why is "HELLO\\2" not equal to """HELLO\2""" in Python 3.8.2

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm trying to figure out why Python 3.8.2 considers this is `true`

```
"HELLO\\WORLD" == """HELLO\WORLD"""
```

But this is `false`

```
"HELLO\\2" == """HELLO\2"""
```

Why is `\2` not interpreted the same in both sides of the string ?

Comment: Did you try looking at the reprs of these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\2` is an octal escape (`\x02`) while `\\2` is an escaped `\`, followed by the numeral `2`. The `W` doesn't have a valid escape so `"\W"` == `"\\W"`

Comment: Then how would I compare the two values ? In my interpretation `"HELLO\\2"` and `"""HELLO\2"""` are both "the string HELLO" with a single backslash 2 after it.

Comment: @ArthurAttout and that interpretation is wrong. It's not clear what you think multiline strings are doing here, did you mean to experiment with _raw strings_ `r"HELLO\2"` (which _would_ be equal to `"HELLO\\2"`)?

Comment: No, that's not true. `"HELLO\\2"` == 'HELLO' + '\\' + '2' while `"""HELLO\2"""` == 'HELLO' + chr(0x2)

Comment: Okay, indeed, I was confusing the triple quotes with raw strings (`r"HELLO\2"`). In this case, it makes sense why `"HELLO\\2" == r"HELLO\2"` is True.